# Calling an Oracle SQL function

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I'm new to the connectivity between Java and Oracle and I'm designing a login page.

I'm attempting to call an Oracle function from JAVA.  Assume the Oracle function is called `FUNCT_PERSON` with 2 IN parameters: `username` and `password` and return the user id which is a `NUMBER`.

Inside the `FUNCT_PERSON` function we use a `SELECT` statement and return user id number if found, otherwise it will return 0.

Here is my code:

```
String sql = "{ ? = call FUNCT_PERSON(?,?) }";
CallableStatement statement = connection.prepareCall(sql);
statement.setString(2,username);
statement.setString(3,password);
statement.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);  

Boolean check = statement.execute();   

if (!check) {
 //proceed to another page
} else {
 //Go back to the login page
}
```

I don't know if what I'm doing is right or not, especially the `Boolean check = statement.execute();` line, because I don't really know what the check is for..

If the function return a user ID, that means it exists in the database and I'll proceed to another page. If not, then it will redirect to the login page.

Comment: Your description makes sense, but I'm not sure what the question is...?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to recover the result of the operation and use it to validate the action to make:

```
String sql = "{ ? = call FUNCT_PERSON(?,?) }";
CallableStatement statement = connection.prepareCall(sql);
statement.setString(2,username);
statement.setString(3,password);
statement.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);  

statement.execute();   
//this is the main line
long id = statement.getLong(1);
if (id > 0) {
    //proceed to another page
} else {
    //Go back to the login page
}
```

Based on [this tutorial](http://jsumon.wordpress.com/2009/12/27/call-oracle-function-from-java-program/)

Answer (score 2):

From the [JAVA Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#execute%28%29):

> The execute method returns a boolean to indicate the form of the first
> result. You must call either the method getResultSet or getUpdateCount
> to retrieve the result; you must call getMoreResults to move to any
> subsequent result(s).
>
> Returns:true if the first result is a ResultSet object; false if the
> first result is an update count or there is no result

So Your check is wrong. `execute` doesn't say if the operation was successful or not.

Comment: But normally, we store the resultSet into an array or cursor, am I correct? But my goal is simply getting the return value, which is a number as oppose to a "set" of numbers.

So if check is true, then it means the select statement return some values, o/w check would be false am I correct?

Comment: @Mr.Y that's explained in my answer. Note that the result of `execute` method just tells you that the statement was executed or not.